# Variables valid or not

Tags: c#

My Question for everyone is, are these valid variables or not valid because i don't want any more errors going forward. I've tried to google and I've looked over stackoverflow for answers so now I ask the community for help with understanding what I'm doing wrong.

```
string First Name;
char MiddleInitial;
string #Name;
int Rank_Num;
string Street/Address;
string StreetAddress2;
string StreetAddress;
double Dim _Cost;
bool Error;
String K;
```

Comment: Well first off we need to know what language you're working in. That being said, a handful of those variables don't look like valid names.

Comment: Sorry updated I'm working with c#

Comment: You might want to google for `c# variable names`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identifiers in C# are subject to the following constraints:

> A name must begin with a letter that could be followed by a sequence of letters, digits (0 - 9) or underscore. The first character in an identifier cannot be a digit.
>
> It must not contain any embedded space or symbol such as? - + ! @ # % ^ & * ( ) [ ] { } . ; : " ' / and . However, an underscore ( _ ) can be used.
>
> It should not be a C# keyword.

[Source](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_basic_syntax.htm).

Therefore,

- `First Name` is not valid, because it contains a space.
- `#Name` is not valid, because it contains an invalid symbol.
- `Street/Address` is not valid, because it contains an invalid symbol.
- `Dim _Cost` is not valid, because it contains a space.

The rest of the identifiers are valid. Note that `string` should always be lowercase in C#.

Comment: sorry thought i added what I'm working with but I'm working with c#

Comment: Updated answer.